# Applescript open "Mail" then open most recent 5 email

Tags: macos, applescript

I am fairly new to Applescript. Even though the language itself is not hard to grasp, some commands are hard to find (For example for "Mail").

What I am trying to achieve is open "Mail" on my computer and select most recent 5 emails and open them in windows. I was able to open windows but the script I had was for "every" email in the mailbox.

The line I used was this.

`set myMessages to every message of myInbox`

What do I have to put instead of every message to open only a given number, lets say 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting every message of the inbox before you refine the list to the first five slows the script down. Ask for the first five of the the inbox.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set myMessages to messages 1 through 5 of inbox
    repeat with aMesseage in myMessages
        open (contents of aMesseage)
    end repeat
end tell
```

EDIT:

```
set myMessages to messages 1 through 5 of inbox whose read status = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try next:

```
set myMessages to every message of myInbox
set subList to items 1 through 5 of myMessages
```

See [AppleScript list manipulation](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/applescript-basic-list-manipulation) for details

Mails in list probably will be ordered (ASC or DESC). So you need first five or last five. For the last five you should also use list size from the link above.